# Granting SQL Server role in a remote server

Tags: sql, powershell, roles

I am working on an activity where I have a table (t1) in server1 which stores servername, userid and role information.

I created a PowerShell script to run on server1, collect these information from the table, connect to the remote server(servername) and grant the requested role to the userid.

Please find the script below:

```
    $SQLServer = "Server1" 
$SQLDatabase = "Db1"
$user = "select userid from T1"
$role = "select access from T1"
$server1 = "Select servername from T1"

<#store the table information in a text file for auditing#>
$Sqlquery = "Select servername,userid,access from T1"
$Test = Invoke-SQLCMD -Query $SqlQuery -serverinstance $SQLServer -Database 
$SQLDatabase
$Test | format-list servername,userid,access| out-file "G:\EP\test.txt"

 $SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server = $Server1; Integrated Security = 
  True"

$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$SqlCmd.CommandText = $SqlQuery
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
$sqlSrv = New-Object 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server' 
"SQLServer\Instance"

foreach ($login in $user)
 {
   $login.AddToRole($role)
 }
 $SqlConnection.Close()
```

While running the above code, I see the following error:

> Method invocation failed because [System.String] does not contain a method named 'AddToRole'.

Answer (score 0):

Where is the `$User` in `foreach ($login in $user)` defined ?

Its null and `foreach` iterates to `null` (expexted behaviour) and `$login` becomes nothing here.

You might have missed setting `$user` here.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I resolved the issue but am not able to share it here because the script is a bit too long and exceeds by 1180 chars.